# pattern among inputted strings

Tags: java, pattern-matching

how can i find a pattern from a series of 3-4 strings ( string being around 10 characters each ) in java.

i.e. to find the pattern among user input strings like A8VMEV6F,N4VSEH5C,A3VEEJ8V,K5VTEH2M ( Here string is 8 characters).

pointers please..

Comment: Your question is very vague, can you please specify what you want to do?

Comment: Your question is in the domain of Artificial Intelligence. If you are interested in joining the ranks of a research group in this field, I would recommend Douglas Hofstadter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variant of the [Levenshtein-Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm to find common substrings. The Wikipedia page is quite instructive and contains code samples.

But may be you should explain first, what is the pattern amongst your samples.

Comment: The pattern to detect is -- "they are all 8-char strings".

Comment: Hmm, there is more: Digits and characters are at the same positions, the third character is always 'V', the fifth 'E'.

Comment: Yes, but I was citing OP's own description. Apparently, the requirement for this case would be to detect "they are all 8-char strings". The wording is not quite up to standard, so I may just be misinterpreting.

Comment: its just that i was given such of codes. now they must have used some pattern to generate it.
i was interested how are such patterns generated? is they any sequence or program by which they are generated?
is it possible for me to generate more such patterns if i have a 5- 10 such generated codes..
i'm not sure this can be done or nt?

Comment: @user1509708 Is the correct anser "buy some more bottles of that drink, with the loyalty program codes in cap"?, scnr ;-)